# When writing a formal report should citations be used in the glossary?

Tags: citations, academic-writing, quotes

First of all hi everyone :-)  In a formal report should the words and phrases defined in the glossary contain citations? Some of the phrases, that are going to be in the glossary, I know so well I don't need to look them up. Some of the phrases are specific to our business (and even specific to our office). On the other hand I really want to quote something the author says [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/virtual-machine-makeuseof-explains/) for a phrase in the glossary. When and how should I site glossary entries, is it only necessary if there's a direct quote?

Comment: Is there a particular style guide you've been told to follow?  If so, which one?

Comment: @MonicaCellio IEEE reference format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know what requires citation and what doesn't , please refer this link :

http://www.library.american.edu/tutorial/citation3.html

1) Ideas, opinions of your own, sharing common knowledge doesn't require citation.

This link will also be helpful to you : http://www.englishclub.com/writing/plagiarism-citation.htm